# Linq statement with two select's and where condition

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have this linq to SQL where I just want to return one Disease with the connecting drug. But what this is doing is returning all Diseases and only populating the drug that meets the where condition.

> Do I need to select the drugs and then the Disease for this to work?

```
    public List<Model.Disease> GetDiseaseById(Guid DiseaseId)
    {
       var Disease = (from Diseases in db.Diseases
                        join dr in db.DrugDiseases on  equals d.DrugId on dr.DrugId 
                        join rdDiseases on rdDiseases.Diseases equals rd.DiseaseId on dr.DiseaseId
                      where (aDrug.DiseaseId == DiseaseId)
                      select new Model.Disease 
                    {
                       DiseaseId = rdDiseases.DiseaseId,
                       DiseaseName = rdDiseases.DiseaseName,
                       drug = (from d in db.Drug
                                join dr1 in db.DrugDiseases on  equals d.DrugId on dr1.DrugId 
                                join rd1Diseases on rdDiseases.Diseases equals rd.DiseaseId on dr1.DiseaseId
                               where (Diseases.DiseaseId == d.DiseaseId && d.DiseaseId == DiseaseId)
                               select new drug
                            {
                              DrugId = d.drug,
                              DrugName = d.drugName}).OrderBy(m => m.DrugName).ToList(),
                   }).OrderBy(d => d.DiseaseName).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
       return Disease;                       
     }
```

Comment: That's because the where condition only applies to the drug.

Comment: hmmm - But should the join being doing it like in SQL

Comment: but I was looking to get a list of Disease with the linked Drug

Comment: I have updated the post with a different linq

Comment: @Jefferson, if I am right, you have 2 tables: db.Diseases and db.Drugs, and you are trying to get the Disease matching DiseaseID passed to the method, and its related drug and return a new named type, right?

Comment: that is correct it should return a list of Diseases with the list of drugs

Comment: @Jefferson, a list? I thought it's just one disease that should be returned. [Let's continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196485/linq-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, you just need one join and this should be straightforward. You should read about [Joins in LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins) and LINQ in general. Also, since you are looking for just one disease, why are you returning a list? The code below should work:

```cs
public Model.Disease GetDiseaseById(Guid DiseaseId)
{
   return (from Disease in db.Diseases
               where Disease.DiseaseId == DiseaseId
               orderby Disease.DiseaseName
               join d in db.Drug on Disease.DiseaseId equals d.DiseasesId
               select new Model.Disease
               {
                   DiseaseId = Disease.DiseaseId
                   DiseaseName = Disease.DiseaseName
                   drug = new { DrugId = d.DrugId, DrugName = d.DrugName }
               }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```